# Getting Specific Data from website via vba, my script is not working properly

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I am new here and I would like to ask for your help. My script only returns the "No title found" even if there's information in the source website.

Could you please help me. here is the script.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetTitle()


Dim xhr As XMLHTTP60, html As HTMLDocument, ws As Worksheet, i As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set xhr = New XMLHTTP60
    Set html = New HTMLDocument

    Dim allData(), title As Object
    allData = ws.UsedRange.Value

    With xhr
        For i = 2 To UBound(allData, 1)
            .Open "GET", "http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/index/index_info?Instrument=" & allData(i, 2), False
            .send
                If .Status <> 200 Then
                    allData(i, 3) = "Status not succeeded" '
                Else
                    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
                    Set title = html.querySelector("#odd")
                    If Not title Is Nothing Then
                        allData(i, 3) = title.innerText
                    Else
                        allData(i, 3) = "No title found"
                    End If
                Set title = Nothing
            End If
        Next
    End With
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(allData, 1), UBound(allData, 2)) = allData
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. Instead, post the code itself (edit your question) so people can copy/paste it if they want to.

Comment: Sorry, i've edited my question above for people to see the code. thank you.

Comment: `html.querySelector("#odd")` searches for an element whose ID is `odd`.  However, the html document does not contain such an element.  But it does contain elements whose class is `odd`.

Comment: I got same result as you. Did you try to use Postman to enter `http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/index/index_info?Instrument=N30EURGI` ?  Or even post it at a Web browser? I did and it seems that there is no odd element. Code is correct, the query is wrong, for this URI. Which element did you try to get?

Comment: @MarceloScofanoDiniz I have not tried both.  i am trying to get the full name of the instrument. in this case. N30EURGI full name is N Financials EUR GI. I could not get the full name from the script..

Comment: @Domenic, may i ask how can i get the fullname? For example N30EURGI full name is N Financials EUR GI? I want to grab the full name of all ISINs in my record.

Comment: If you go [download and install Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/) and at Workspaces, GET, send the link above, you will see that this string _N Financials EUR GI_ is nowhere. So, your code is correct, but you are not asking the NASDAQ API correctly.